# System.Security.Cryptography.Cryptographic Exception {"Key does not exist.\r\n"}

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I'm reading private and public keys from XML String in my C# program. Encryption(with private key) works fine. But when it comes to Decryption(with public Key) it throws following error.

**System.Security.Cryptography.Cryptographic Exception {"Key does not exist.\r\n"}**

```
var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();

rsa.FromXmlString(_privateKey);
rsa.FromXmlString(_publicKey);

byte[] messagee = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("win win win");

byte[] encrypted = rsa.Encrypt(messagee, false);
string encString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(encrypted);

byte[] decrypt = rsa.Decrypt(encrypted,false);
string decString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decrypt);
```

Why is that? I searched every where, but couldn't find any solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: which line is giving you error?

Comment: @ : - byte[] decrypt = rsaa.Decrypt(encrypted,false);

Comment: Doing `UTF8.GetString` on the encrypted bytes is going to cause problems, the result of the encryption is not a valid string, treat it as a sequence of bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this [link](http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/36454-Cryptography.aspx), it might be helpful. 
The problem is in the following lines...

```
rsa.FromXmlString(_privateKey);
rsa.FromXmlString(_publicKey);
```

...because private key is overridden by the public key..